# Flushing stdout appears to have no effect if reading from stdin

Tags: c, linux, perl, cygwin

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
$| = 1;
foreach (1..5) {
    print $_ . "\r";
    sleep 1;
}
print "\n";
```

This behaves as expected: the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 overwrite each other on the console.

```
$ ./loop.pl | hexdump -C
00000000  31 0d 32 0d 33 0d 34 0d  35 0d 0a                 |1.2.3.4.5..|
```

However, a different script (intended to show hide the large output of a long-running program like this: `long_running_program | tee output | ./progr`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
$| = 1;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print $_ . "\r";
}
print "\n";
```

produces different behavior when input is redirected:

```
 perl -wle 'foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl
```

No output is seen for five seconds, then a '5' can be seen. Yet hexdump shows the same output (after five seconds)

```
$ perl -wle 'foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl | hexdump.exe -C
00000000  31 0d 32 0d 33 0d 34 0d  35 0d 0a                 |1.2.3.4.5..|
```

This is not Perl-specific. The following C code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    printf("%d\r", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
puts("\n");
```

shows digits overwriting each other, but

```
#define SIZE (256 * 1024)
char buffer[SIZE];
int line = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin)) {
    printf("%d\r", ++line);
    fflush(stdout);
}
puts("\n");
```

when at the end of a pipe, only shows output after the input is exhausted.

Not even

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

appears to help.

I tried all these through an SSH connection to a remote Linux (RHEL6) system, and locally under Cygwin.

(Edited with corrections from @Fredrik and @usr)

Comment: printf(%d\r", i);  You are missing a quote ”

Comment: You should make `stdout` unbuffered (not `stdin`): `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`.

Comment: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` doesn't help either :(

Comment: @Bulletmagnet This `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 long_running_program | tee output | ./progr`?

Comment: The question does not have a [mre] for the C case. Pipes are not line-buffered. perl -wle does not flush

Comment: By the way, you aren't reading from STDIN (at least not directly). `<>` is short for `<ARGV>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong program. You turned off output buffering in the second program of the pipeline, but not the first.

---

STDOUT is line-buffered if connected to a terminal, block-buffered otherwised.

Line-buffered: Flushed when a Line Feed is output.

Block-buffered: Flushed when the buffer is filled.

Since the STDOUT of the first program of the pipeline (the input generator) is connected to a pipe, its output is block-buffered. And since the buffer is large enough to hold the entirety of the program's output, your input generator doesn't actually output anything until it exits.

Change

```
perl -wle 'foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl
```

to

```
perl -wle '$| = 1; foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl
```

But what if you have no control over the program? You can sometimes coax other program to turn off buffering by using `unbuffer`.

```
unbuffer perl -wle 'foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl
```

Comment: Thanks for a well-written explanation, and for the suggestion to use `unbuffer`, which worked.

Answer (score -1):

In most of those examples, you're piping output that only has carriage returns (until the program ends and prints a newline (Or two for the C version)) to programs that are reading a newline-terminated line at a time. Of course you're not going to see output from the second program until the first program ends -- it's waiting on a newline or end of file to return the first line.

---

In the `perl -wle 'foreach (1..5) { print $_; sleep 1 }' | ./progr.pl` case, yes, there are newlines thanks to the `-l` option, but the output is buffered because it's to a pipe, and `progr.pl` doesn't see any input until the first part finishes. Add a `$|=1;` at the beginning before the loop and you'll get different results.

Comment: The Perl one-liner's output has no carriage returns. It has newlines. Only the second program outputs carriage returns.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet The one-liner also buffers its output because stdout is a pipe. The progr.pl script doesn't see any input until the one-liner's finished. You have to flush output; see edit.